# Can I host my angular6 web app in MacOs server?

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mean-stack, macos-sierra

I am newly to host the web application to server. Now I am using macOS Sierra Version 10.12.3. I developed angular6 web application. Can I setup my desktop as macOS server and host my angular web application?

Comment: Google is your best friend! I'm sure you will find your answer

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can, and not only on the Local Area Network, but on the Wide Area Network. And if you buy a domain name you can attach this name to your server. At the end of the day after you executed 'ng build --prod --aot', everything will be compiled to plain Javascripts just like any other websites regardless of any JS frameworks. Just try to look up on google about hosting a website on MacOS server.

Comment: is it need for any static IP?

Comment: @Ram, yes you need a static IP address from your ISP and that cost extra money. On top of hosting yourself and getting a domain, maintain your server, that is not cost efficient in my own opinion and too much hassle. So far if Angular is concerned, you can host it whether and whichever ways you prefer. Angular is no different than others in terms of hosting and deployment.